# I have this problem in flutter when I called a function " 'Future<String>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'"

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this problem with variables in Dart, I want to read the String value from my function `read()` but I got this error :

> The argument type 'Future' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'

This is my function code :

```
read() async {
  final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  String key = 'Code_Abo';
  String value = prefs.get(key ) ?? 0;
  // String rr = value.toString();
  //print(value.toString());
  return(value);
}
```

and here i want to use the returned value (as a string):

```
QrImage(
  data: read(),
  version: QrVersions.auto,
  size: 250.0,
  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 75.0, right: 75.0),
  // embeddedImage: AssetImage('assets/logo.png'),
),
```

Thank U in advance ...

Comment: You should add await: `String value = (await prefs.get(key)) ?? 0;`

Comment: doesn't work, i got a null value

Comment: Is that `prefs.getString(key)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guest that your `QrImage` be called from `build(BuildContext)` method. In fact, the `read()` method return `Future<dynamic>` instead of `String`. That's effect of `async` keyword. Another story, you should not await any thing in the `build(BuildContext)` method. The solution for you that's prepare a placeholder during load the data. One more thing, that's should be `prefs.getString(String)` instead of `prefs.get(String)`

Demo code:

```
class Demo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DemoSate createState() => _DemoSate();
}

class _DemoSate extends State<Demo> {
  String data;

  Future<String> read() async {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final String key = 'Code_Abo';
    return prefs.getString(key) ?? "";
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    read().then((value) {
      setState(() {
        data = value;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return data == null
        ? Text('Loading')
        : QrImage(
            data: data,
            version: QrVersions.auto,
            size: 250.0,
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 75.0, right: 75.0),
            // embeddedImage: AssetImage('assets/logo.png'),
          );
  }
}
```

*Updated: The same idea with a better solution provided by mr.Abion47 in the next answer below.*

Comment: You shouldn't use a complex setup with `initState` and `setState` and a data field just to wait for and handle the results of a future. That's literally the exact situation that `FutureBuilder` was designed for.

Comment: Thank U for your comment. You are right. I will update it soon.

Answer (score 1):

`read` returns a future, and you need to wait for the future to complete if you want to use the string value it returns. If you want to use it in a widget, use a `FutureBuilder`:

```
FutureBuilder<String>(
  future: read(),
  builder: (_, snapshot) {
    if (!snapshot.hasData) {
      // Return something to show the future hasn't completed yet
      return CircularProgressIndicator();
    }

    return QrImage(
        data: snapshot.data,
        version: QrVersions.auto,
        size: 250.0,
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 75.0, right: 75.0),
       // embeddedImage: AssetImage('assets/logo.png'),
    );
  },
),
```